# iOS Game Center baloons menu

Tags: ios

I have one questing regarding iOS Game Center baloons menu. I am wondering which kind od iOS frameworks (Core animation??) is used for creation of this wonderful menu. Here is image below to depict of what I mean exactly:

[image]

Baloons have soft motions and when user taps on one of them there is crazy baloons motion effect. Can anyone provide some links to some code example which describes how we can make something similar. Or is there anywhere some kind of similar menu for general usage?

Thanks!

Comment: you could get other kind of menus on GitHub Or CocoaControls too

Comment: i think core animation would be enough. For the bubble effect, i think it is a circular bezier path, and are animating its circular path , and for bounce and move CAKeyFrameAnimation would be good to use.

Answer (score 2):

For Getting the bubble kind of animation, we don't need the core animation.We will use core animation for moving the bubble and bouncing the bubble.

**Creating the bubble:**

Create a view for Bubble

**BubbleView.h** and **.m**

```
@interface BubbleView : UIView

@property (assign) CGFloat top;
@property (assign) CGFloat bot;
@property (assign) CGFloat leftt;
@property (assign) CGFloat rightt;


@end
```

These serve as the four control points for the bezier path. We will be modifying these four points to get the bubble effect.

```
@implementation BubbleView


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [self drawBubbleWithFrame:rect top:_top bot:_bot leftt:_leftt rightt:_rightt];
}

- (void)drawBubbleWithFrame: (CGRect)frame top: (CGFloat)top bot: (CGFloat)bot leftt: (CGFloat)leftt rightt: (CGFloat)rightt
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.019 green: 0.551 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
    
    //// Oval Drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 6, 0);
    
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [ovalPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(rightt, 40)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(bot, 80) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(rightt, 62.09) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(bot + 22.09, 80)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(leftt, 40) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(bot - 22.09, 80) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(leftt, 62.09)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(top, 0) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(leftt, 17.91) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(top - 22.09, 0)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(rightt, 40) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(top + 22.09, 0) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(rightt, 17.91)];
    [ovalPath closePath];
    [color2 setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
    
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}


@end
```

Now let's add this to the view :

I created a circle of size 80x80, and hence their control points would be 40,40,0,80

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    _bubView=[[BubbleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 150, 150)];
    _bubView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _bubView.top=40;
    _bubView.bot=40;
    _bubView.leftt=0;
    _bubView.rightt=80;

    [self.view addSubview:_bubView];
            
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the bubble is not shaking, it looks like just a circle.

Let's shake it!

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    _bubView=[[BubbleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 150, 150)];
    _bubView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _bubView.top=40;
    _bubView.bot=40;
    _bubView.leftt=0;
    _bubView.rightt=80;

    [self.view addSubview:_bubView];
    
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(applyRandomMoves) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
}

-(void)applyRandomMoves{
    
    int toprandNum = rand() % (45 - 35) + 35; //create the random number.
    int botrandNum = rand() % (45 - 35) + 35;
    int leftrandNum = rand() % (0 - -5) + -5;
    int rightrandNum = rand() % (85 - 75) + 75;
    
    _bubView.top=toprandNum;
    _bubView.bot=botrandNum;
    _bubView.leftt=leftrandNum;
    _bubView.rightt=rightrandNum;
    
    [_bubView setNeedsDisplay];

    
}
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]

You can add some shadows and make the bubble little more realistic:Let's add some code to `drawBubbleWithFrame`

```
- (void)drawBubbleWithFrame: (CGRect)frame top: (CGFloat)top bot: (CGFloat)bot leftt: (CGFloat)leftt rightt: (CGFloat)rightt
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.019 green: 0.551 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* color3 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.317 green: 0.47 blue: 0.863 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadow2Color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 1];
    
    //// Shadow Declarations
    NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow setShadowColor: shadowColor];
    [shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.1, -0.1)];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius: 12];
    NSShadow* shadow2 = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow2 setShadowColor: shadow2Color];
    [shadow2 setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(4.1, 2.1)];
    [shadow2 setShadowBlurRadius: 5];
    NSShadow* shadow3 = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow3 setShadowColor: UIColor.blackColor];
    [shadow3 setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.1, 1.1)];
    [shadow3 setShadowBlurRadius: 5];
    
    //// Oval Drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 6, 2);
    
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [ovalPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(rightt, 40)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(bot, 80) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(rightt, 62.09) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(bot + 22.09, 80)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(leftt, 40) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(bot - 22.09, 80) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(leftt, 62.09)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(top, 0) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(leftt, 17.91) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(top - 22.09, 0)];
    [ovalPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(rightt, 40) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(top + 22.09, 0) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(rightt, 17.91)];
    [ovalPath closePath];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow3.shadowOffset, shadow3.shadowBlurRadius, [shadow3.shadowColor CGColor]);
    [color2 setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
    
    ////// Oval Inner Shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIRectClip(ovalPath.bounds);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 0, NULL);
    
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGColorGetAlpha([shadow2.shadowColor CGColor]));
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
    {
        UIColor* opaqueShadow = [shadow2.shadowColor colorWithAlphaComponent: 1];
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow2.shadowOffset, shadow2.shadowBlurRadius, [opaqueShadow CGColor]);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceOut);
        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
        
        [opaqueShadow setFill];
        [ovalPath fill];
        
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
    }
    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow.shadowOffset, shadow.shadowBlurRadius, [shadow.shadowColor CGColor]);
    [color3 setStroke];
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [ovalPath stroke];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

This gives the effect:

[image]

You can playground the bubble properties like colour, shadow,shape,blur,bubble outer path etc, and animate them all based on the requirements.

You can later add the animation to the _bubView layer to move it or to bounce it!

Comment: Thanks a lot on this very detailed and descriptive answer. Howewer I am not getting the same baloon glow and on tap movements. How can we get same baloon like in iOS Game Center. Does we need baloons image backgrounds or pure drawing code is enough to draw same baloons. The ballons must be nice like Game Center. And also on press animation is also important. I would loved to check this as answer but im am not getting the absolute asnwer. Anyway tahnks a lot!

Comment: you could use background images like that and set the background for the circles mentioned in my answer. Yes those animations could be possible. THey are just making that bubble vibrate along with the animation I mentioned here. For that vibration you can use CAKeyFrameAnimation.